# resolving svn binary conflicts

Tags: svn, conflict

I use svn for a project im working on with a couple of other developers. Svn works fine for source control however we are all ways getting conflicts when we commit the dlls.

When i do i resolve the conflict (which deletes my dlls as the diff program cant handle binary files) then have to rebuild to commit. How are you meant to resolve conflicts like this?

Edit:

The dlls are in a separate svn folder as the project is a game mod and non programmers need access to the latest builds.

Comment: Do you have a specific need to actually have the DLLs in SVN?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mentioned in other answers here: you shouldn't version your generated dlls in the first place. But if you really **have** to version them, then you can resolve a conflict without using a diff tool which removes your dll files:

For every conflicted file, Subversion places three extra unversioned files in your working copy:

filename.mine

This is your file as it existed in your working copy before you updated your working copy—that is, without conflict markers. This file has only your latest changes in it. (If Subversion considers the file to be unmergeable, the .mine file isn't created, since it would be identical to the working file.)

filename.rOLDREV

This is the file that was the BASE revision before you updated your working copy. That is, the file that you checked out before you made your latest edits.

filename.rNEWREV

This is the file that your Subversion client just received from the server when you updated your working copy. This file corresponds to the HEAD revision of the repository.

Here OLDREV is the revision number of the file in your .svn directory, and NEWREV is the revision number of the repository HEAD.

Now, to resolve such a conflict, remove the additional files you don't want:

- if you want to keep your own dll, delete the files filename.rOLDREV, filename.rNEWREV
- if you want to keep the dll from the repository, delete the files filename.rOLDREV and filename.mine, then copy filename.rNEWREV to filename

after that, execute

```
svn resolved filename
```

to tell Subversion that you resolved the conflict yourself.

Comment: I think this is what im after (will have to give it ago next time) as i didnt know if you could delete the one you didnt want with out it breaking svn

Comment: you cannot "break svn" with the tools the svn client gives you. at the most you can bring chaos into your source tree

Answer (score 7):

If it's a DLL that you are BUILDING (rather than an external one you have no source for) then the source should be in source control, not the binary.

If you don't want to include it in that particular repository then you can include it as an svn:external.

Comment: I have binaries that I have to reference in some of my repositories.  They usually don't change much and I typically share them among several projects so I just use an external repository for them.

Answer (score 4):

Generally, you wouldn't store your own compiled DLLs in source control at all. Do you have a specific reason that you need to do this?

I set up my development environments so that anybody can build any of my project components independently of anybody else. In this way, the only thing that is in my source control system is my *source* code. This has a number of benefits:

- It avoids binary file conflicts when trying to check in DLLs or EXEs
- The volume of data tracked by your source control system is much smaller, making it faster
- When developers always build their own DLLs, then they can be reasonably sure that the source code they have matches the compiled file. If you're using something that somebody else built, then you can never be sure.

As mentioned in the comments, it can be perfectly reasonable to store third party DLLs in your source control system, particularly if you don't actually have the source for them. I've also worked on projects where we stored distribution files (`.tar.gz` etc) for various open source libraries in source control, then had a whole system of `Makefile`s that built *those* libraries as part of a build-everything target.

Comment: I think it's fine and normal to include DLLs in source control - but only those of third party libraries, not your own source code. For instance, I include the NUnit binary in source control rather than putting the source code in there and recompiling that every time.

Comment: "all ways getting conflicts when we commit the dlls." I don't think he means third party libraries. You shouldn't commit 3rd parties all the time... Much less get conflicts.

Comment: @Martinho: Sure. I'm only taking issue with the statement of "Generally you wouldn't store DLLs in source control at all." I think it would be good for Greg to clarify that a bit.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I updated my answer to clarify what I meant. And of course, my answer was in the context of how I interpreted the original question (where "the dlls" meant "the binaries I just built").

Answer (score 4):

For binary files, most of the time, you want to accept either version of it. For example, if the file in question is an executable tool, then typically one version might be newer than the other, and that may be the one you want to use.

**(This is not always the case, though, and of course SVN has no way of knowing this. Basically, you have to know what was changed, and if not, talk to others who have made changes, as always when working together at a project)**

To accept the version that is in the branch you are merging from, use:

```
svn resolve --accept=theirs-full path/to/filename
```

To accept the version that was previously in the current branch, use:

```
svn resolve --accept=mine-full path/to/filename
```

Sometimes, SVN will refuse to use `theirs-full` with a warning:

```
svn: warning: W195024: Inapplicable conflict resolution option given for conflicted path
```

This happens, for example, if the file was modified locally ("mine") and deleted remotely ("theirs"). In that case, you have to either

1. Delete the file using `svn rm path/to/filename` (which accepts "their" change, which is to delete the file).
2. Copy files manually like in the accepted answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/410767/2279059, rather than using command-line options that are intended for what you are trying to do.

If you know both files are identical (but SVN is still marking them as conflict for reasons already stated), you can also use

```
svn resolve --accept=working path/to/filename
```

While this, in the case of identical files, is effectively the same as all other commands, SVN will not cowardly refuse to execute it.

Comment: `W195024` also seems to happen for `svn resolve --accept theirs-full` on a "local file edit, incoming file delete or move upon merge" conflict, and deleting the file and then accepting `working` seems to do the trick. Thank you.

Comment: Follow-up: I _also_ had to `svn rm` them, as after the previous two steps they seemed to be left as "missing" rather than deleted.

Comment: @TBBle Thank you for clarifying this. Also noticing you used the word "also" when I didn't give any explanation other than "SVN is a (pardon my French)" :D. I will edit my post. Having to use `svn rm` rather than just deleting the file is consistent with common SVN behavior. You have to explicitly tell SVN that you want to delete something.

Answer (score 2):

It is reasonable to also have binaries in version control:

- It avoids the hassle of rebuilding for people who only use the binary.
- The binary is nailed down when you release.

To make this work the binary needs to always correspond to the sources.
So if you have merged sources you need to rebuild the binary from them,
picking one of the binaries from the merged versions won't do.

Comment: Agreed, having binaries in source control makes sense if you work together with non-programmers on a project.

Comment: Good advice, perhaps even SVN's rationale for its behavior, but not a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your dlls have the `svn:mime-type` property set to `application/octet-stream` or some other non-text type.

```
svn propget *.dll
svn propset svn:mime-type application/octet-stream *.dll
```

You will still have to actually *resolve* conflicts when they occur.

And check the [File Content Type](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.props.file-portability.html#svn.advanced.props.special.mime-type) chapter of the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

So if you have the *.dlls in a separate folder its much easier to do as follows:

1. Directly before you build your change update your *.dll folder better also update your sources, if you trust, that your colleagues only commit compilable source code. (in case of conflict (what would be your fault at that point, as you changed something before you updated to latest revision))
2. Do your build.
3. Directly commit the outcome.

Alternatively:

do not build to the path in the directory, build to somewhere outside, until you're are happy with whatever is the outcome.

Then proceed as follows:

1. Update your working copy of the dlls folder (if there is any conflict its your fault and solve the conflict by "keep theirs")
2. Copy your working .dlls to the working copy
3. Inform your colleagues that you will commit a new revision (you can let this step away)
4. Commit your work if there is any conflict it should be their fault.

You have two possibilities now:

5a. You're a very detestable person and solve the problem by keeping mine.

5b. You work as you should work... Read the log file and find out who also committed during the short time you needed to copy your work to the folder and pressed commit. Speak to that colleague. Agree on further course of action.